# Degeneracy in Linear Programs

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

This is a version of Problem-3.8 (Bertsimas - Introduction to Linear Optimization),

> Consider the linear programming problem of minimizing $c'x$ over all $x \in P$, where $P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \leq b\}$ is a given bounded and non-empty polyhedron Let, $$Q = \{(x, t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | Ax \leq tb, \, \, t \in [0, 1]\}$$

> (a) Give an example of $P$ and $Q$, with $n = 2$, for which the zero vector (in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$)  is a degenerate basic feasible solution in $Q$; then show the example in a figure.

How can the zero vector be degenerate as we need more than 3 constraints to be tight at this point. My approach,

In terms of active constraints, if we have more than $(n+1)$ active constraints in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ we have a degenerate basic solution. I thought of an example of such $P$ and $Q$ where we have the origin as degenerate. $P = \{x : x_2\leq ax_1, x_1 \leq 1, x_2 \geq 0\}$ ; this represents a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ; if we sketch $Q$ we get degeneracy at origin. But, what I want is a more general approach to figure out such cases as I did this via hit and trial.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "a more general approach to figure out such cases" but it might help to think about the feasible region, basic feasible solutions (BFS), and degeneracy geometrically. As I am sure you know, a BFS is a vertex of the feasible region. This means it is the unique intersection of the hyperplanes given by the active constraints. In $n$-dimensional space we need to intersect $n$ hyperplanes to define a point. If we add one more hyperplane that also passes through that point, which corresponds to adding an extra active constraint, we have a degenerate BFS.

Comment: This means that if you want to devise an example in small dimensions where a specific point is a degenerate BFS, you could probably just draw what it would look like, and reverse engineer the constraints. In your example specifically though, at 0, all of your constraints end up looking like $0 \leq 0$ which is active (as is $t>=0$) so any two linearly independent constraints in $x_1$ and $x_2$ should work. From there you just need to add constraints so $P$ satisfies the requirements of being bounded and non-empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We shall try to address (b).

We assume that $A$ is some $m\times n$ real matrix and $b\in\mathbb R^m$, $m\in\mathbb N$.

Suppose first that the zero vector minimizes $(c, 0)'y$ over all $y \in Q$.
Thus $(c, 0)'y\ge 0$ for each $y\in Q$. Let $x\in P$ be any vector.
Then $(x,1)\in Q$, so $c'x=(c, 0)'(x,1)\ge 0$.

Suppose now that $c'x\ge 0$ for each $x\in P$. Since $0\in Q$ and $(c,0)'0=0$, it remains to show that $(c,0)'y\ge 0$ for any vector $y\in Q$. There exists $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and $t\in [0,1]$ such that $Ax\le tb$ and $y=(x,t)$. If $t>0$ then $A(t^{-1}x)\le b$, so $t^{-1}x\in P$. Then $(c,0)'y=c'x=t^{-1}c'x\ge 0$. But if $t=0$ then we obtain $Ax\le 0$, and a priory $x$ can be outside $P$ and $c'x$ can be negative.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, But I was looking for answer to (a)

Comment: @28ADY0901 I can try to answer (a), if you recall what is a degenerate basic feasible solution.

Comment: In terms of active constraints, if we have more than $(n+1)$ active constraints in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ we have a degenerate basic solution. I thought of an example of such $P$ and $Q$ where we have the origin as degenerate. 

$P = \{x : x_2\leq ax_1, x_1 \leq 1, x_2 \geq 0\}$ ; this represents a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ; if we sketch $Q$ we get degeneracy at origin. But, what I want is a more general approach to figure out such cases as I did this via hit and trial.